# XSLT functions with an object as params

Tags: xslt-2.0

I've been going through some of our XSLT code and I'm starting to notice quite a bit of duplicate code.  As I do like code DRY and am an OO guy, I would like to make some simple functions and call them for any of this duplicate logic.  My issue is that in some cases I'd be passing in 10 parameters or some such where as another call would only be passing in 4.  I know you can default parameters, but having 10 parameters to a function is just ugly.  In a normal OO programming language, you'd create an object with 10 properties and pass that in which allows for the properties to grow without having to change any callers or the signature of the question in general.  I know we have complex types in xsl.  So should I create a separate xsd for these functions and then pass it in like:

```
<xsl:function name="foo:doSomething">
    <xsl:param name="someComplexType"/>
    ...
    <xsl:variable name="field1" select="someComplexType/field1" />
</xsl:function>
```

But then how should I build my new type with some 10 different selectors?  Is this even the best way to do this?  Or should I just pass in all 10 params?  Conceptually the 10 different params are related to one object so it makes sense and seems cleaner to do it this way, but I'm still looking for more of a best practice for xslt going forward.

Comment: If you want to work with complex schema types, then you need a schema-aware processor like Saxon 9 EE. Do you have that? But as long as you don't specify a type in an `as` attribute you can pass in anything.

Comment: I believe we have a processor able to handle complex schema types.  How do I create the object, though, am I doing a xsl:variable element with a large concat statement (not sure how many parameters concat can take even).  What is the method for generating complex schema types outside of the document I am processing?

Comment: You will need to define any types in a schema. As for creating instances inside your XSLT code, that is done as with any XML, you simply construct it using literals or if element names have to be computed, using `xsl:element`. So `<xsl:variable name="foo1" as="element(foo, fooType)"><foo>... </foo></xsl:variable>`.

Comment: I see @MartinHonnen.  So I could have something like `<foo><field1><xsl:value-of select="..."></field1>...</foo>`.  I like that better.  If you want to state that as an answer I'll mark this as complete.

Comment: I have put the essence of the comments into an answer to allow you to accept it and close down this issue.

Comment: One last question @MartinHonnen, this works great except that it inherits my target namespace which I don't want.  Is there a way to not have a namespace in this tree?  It would be nice if inherit-namespaces worked with xsl:variable

Comment: Simply use `xmlns=""` on the `xsl:variable` or on the foo element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to define a complex type with a schema and use that in XSLT then you need a schema-aware XSLT 2.0 or 3.0 processor like Saxon 9 Enterprise Edition.

You can however pass in an element with sub elements, without using schemas, as with XSLT 2.0 you can easily construct temporary XML nodes in your XSLT code, as in

```
<xsl:variable name="foo1" as="element(foo)">
  <foo>
    <bar><xsl:value-of select="whatever"/></bar>
    <baz><xsl:value-of select="whatelse"/></baz>
    ...
  </foo>
</xsl:variable>
```